# Parallel Filtering of CUDA Array (Compute Architecture)

Tags: cuda, f#, gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to develop a framework for performing standard functional sequence operations (map, filter, fold, etc) in F# where the computations are performed on the GPU (using CUDA) instead of the CPU.

I've had some success implementing a CUDA map function such that I can write

```
let result = 
    cudaArray 
    |> CudaArray.map <@ fun x -> x ** 3.0  @> 
    |> Array.ofCudaArray
```

This is relatively straightforward because all of the operations are performed elementwise.

Now, I am interested in writing a similar system for filtering by some predicate.  I'm thinking about implementing the predicate as another map function which returns a boolean array but I need to find a way of reducing the array of interest to one where the matching boolean array element has a value of true.

I found this article (http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-optimized-filtering-warp-aggregated-atomics/) which describes what looks like a very nice method of solving this problem, it boils down to using the following function to index elements in the destination array:

```
// warp-aggregated atomic increment
__device__
int atomicAggInc(int *ctr) {
  int mask = __ballot(1);
  // select the leader
  int leader = __ffs(mask) – 1;
  // leader does the update
  int res;
  if(lane_id() == leader)
    res = atomicAdd(ctr, __popc(mask));
  // broadcast result
  res = warp_bcast(res, leader);
  // each thread computes its own value
  return res + __popc(mask & ((1 << lane_id()) – 1));
} // atomicAggInc
```

The problem is, I understand from the article that *warp_bcast* is only supported by Compute Capability 3.0 cards or greater.

I am interested to know if there is there is some alternative to *warp_bcast* for Compute Capability < 3.0 or if there is some other approach I can use to solve this problem without sacrificing all of the huge performance gains described in the article? (To be clear, I'm absolutely open to completely different approaches to the one described in the article listed if they can help me crack this.)